# RAID 1+0 redundancy and data-loss recovery capability against RAID 1

Tags: raid1, raid10, raid0

I have a HP ProLiant server with two SCSI drives. I wanted to set up a RAID 1 array but the RAID configurator only allowed me a RAID 0 or a RAID 1+0 array.
When either of my drive fails can I recover the data upon RAID 1+0 configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the RAID 1+0 configuration with 2 disks only behaves like a RAID 1 configuration

Comment: No prob. The advantadge of this is that you can easily upgrade to a 1+0 array just by adding the extra disks